# Scrapy script cannot upload to s3 when using runner = CrawlerRunner(): only works using process = CrawlerProcess()

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, scrapy

I have a weird issue where my script *does* upload data to my s3 with no issues using `process = CrawlerProcess()` (exampled below), but when I attempt to run my script which does contain various classes (12 in total), sequentially it doesn't send to s3 when using `runner = CrawlerRunner()` (also shown below).

Also, sometimes when I run the `process = CrawlerProcess()` , it will only send to the 11/12 folders but hardly ever to the top (1st) class

I have a script that is running 12 classes (a portion exampled below), all going class will export to a specific on my s3. Any thoughts what could be causing issue?

```
import scrapy
import boto3
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose, Join
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging


class JobsSpider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "indeed"
    allowed_domains = ["indeed.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=%22owner+operator%22&l=atlanta"]
#
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'jsonlines',
        'URI SCHEME':'s3',
        'FEED_URI':'s3://<key_data>@<bucket_name>/folder1/folder2/data-file-indeed-%(time)s.json',
        'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING':'UTF',
        'FEED_TEMPDIR':'/home/user/Desktop/projects/test_folder/',
        'FEED_STORE_EMPTY' : 'True'
        }
#
    def parse(self, response):
        #jobs = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result clickcard')]").getall()
        jobs = response.xpath('//div[@class="jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result"]')
#
        for job in jobs:
            #post_id = job.xpath(".//*[@class='title']/div/@id").getall()
            title = job.xpath(".//*[@class='title']/a/@title").get(default='not-found')
            location = job.xpath(".//*[@class='sjcl']/span/text()").get(default='not-found')
            location2 = job.xpath(".//div[@class='location accessible-contrast-color-location']/text()").get(default='not-found')
            #company = job.xpath("//span[@class='company']/text()").getall()
            posting_link = job.xpath('*//@href').get(default='not-found')
            posting_url = "https://indeed.com" + posting_link
            company = job.xpath(".//span[@class='company']//a/text()").get(default='not-found')
            company2 = job.xpath(".//span[@class='company']/text()").get(default='not-found')
#
#
#
            yield Request(posting_url, callback=self.parse_page, meta={'posting_url':posting_url, 'title':title, 'company':company, 'company2':company2, 'location':location, 'location2':location2})
#
        relative_next_url = response.xpath('//link[@rel="next"]/@href').get()
        absolute_next_url = "https://indeed.com" + relative_next_url
#
        yield Request(absolute_next_url, callback=self.parse)
#
    def parse_page(self, response):
        posting_url = response.meta.get('posting_url')
        company2 = response.meta.get('company2')
        title = response.meta.get('title')
        location = response.meta.get('location')
        company = response.meta.get('company')
        location2 = response.meta.get('location2')
        post_id = response.meta.get('post_id')
#
#
#
        job_descriptions_2=response.xpath('//*[@id="jobDescriptionText"]/*').get(default='not-found')
        job_descriptions=response.xpath('//*[@class="jobsearch-jobDescriptionText"]/*').get(default='not-found')
        job_descriptions_3=response.xpath('//*[@class="jobsearch-JobComponent-description  icl-u-xs-mt--md  "]/*').get(default='not-found')
        #job_descriptions="".join(line for line in response.xpath('//*[@class="jobsearch-jobDescriptionText"]/text()').extract()).strip()
        posted_on_date= response.xpath('//*[@class="jobsearch-JobMetadataFooter"]/text()').get(default='not-found')
#
#
        yield{
        'posting_url':posting_url,
        'posted_on_date':posted_on_date,
        'title':title,
        'location':location,
        'location2':location2,
        'company':company,
        'company2':company2,
        'job_descriptions':job_descriptions,
        'job_descriptions_2':job_descriptions_2,
        'job_descriptions_3':job_descriptions_3
        }

################################################################
class JobsSpider2(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "indeed"
    allowed_domains = ["indeed.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=%22owner+operator%22&l=augusta"]
#
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'jsonlines',
        'URI SCHEME':'s3',
        'FEED_URI':'s3://<key_data>@<bucket_name>/folder1/folder2/data-file-indeed-%(time)s.json',
        #'FEED_URI':'augusta-indeed-%(time)s.json',
        #'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING':'utf-8'
        'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING':'UTF',
        'FEED_TEMPDIR':''/home/user/Desktop/projects/test_folder/',
        'FEED_STORE_EMPTY' : 'True'
        }
#
    def parse(self, response):
        #jobs = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result clickcard')]").getall()
        jobs = response.xpath('//div[@class="jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result"]')
#
        for job in jobs:
            #post_id = job.xpath(".//*[@class='title']/div/@id").getall()
            title = job.xpath(".//*[@class='title']/a/@title").get(default='not-found')
            location = job.xpath(".//*[@class='sjcl']/span/text()").get(default='not-found')
            location2 = job.xpath(".//div[@class='location accessible-contrast-color-location']/text()").get(default='not-found')
            #company = job.xpath("//span[@class='company']/text()").getall()
            posting_link = job.xpath('*//@href').get(default='not-found')
            posting_url = "https://indeed.com" + posting_link
            company = job.xpath(".//span[@class='company']//a/text()").get(default='not-found')
            company2 = job.xpath(".//span[@class='company']/text()").get(default='not-found')
#
#
#
            yield Request(posting_url, callback=self.parse_page, meta={'posting_url':posting_url, 'title':title, 'company':company, 'company2':company2, 'location':location, 'location2':location2})
#
        relative_next_url = response.xpath('//link[@rel="next"]/@href').get()
        absolute_next_url = "https://indeed.com" + relative_next_url
#
        yield Request(absolute_next_url, callback=self.parse)
#
    def parse_page(self, response):
        posting_url = response.meta.get('posting_url')
        company2 = response.meta.get('company2')
        title = response.meta.get('title')
        location = response.meta.get('location')
        company = response.meta.get('company')
        location2 = response.meta.get('location2')
        post_id = response.meta.get('post_id')
#
#
#
        job_descriptions_2=response.xpath('//*[@id="jobDescriptionText"]/*').get(default='not-found')
        job_descriptions=response.xpath('//*[@class="jobsearch-jobDescriptionText"]/*').get(default='not-found')
        job_descriptions_3=response.xpath('//*[@class="jobsearch-JobComponent-description  icl-u-xs-mt--md  "]/*').get(default='not-found')
        #job_descriptions="".join(line for line in response.xpath('//*[@class="jobsearch-jobDescriptionText"]/text()').extract()).strip()
        posted_on_date= response.xpath('//*[@class="jobsearch-JobMetadataFooter"]/text()').get(default='not-found')
#
#
        yield{
        'posting_url':posting_url,
        'posted_on_date':posted_on_date,
        'title':title,
        'location':location,
        'location2':location2,
        'company':company,
        'company2':company2,
        'job_descriptions':job_descriptions,
        'job_descriptions_2':job_descriptions_2,
        'job_descriptions_3':job_descriptions_3
        }

#################################################################

This works below:

process = CrawlerProcess()
#
process.crawl(JobsSpider1)
process.crawl(JobsSpider2)
#process.crawl(JobsSpider3)
#process.crawl(JobsSpider4)
#process.crawl(JobsSpider5)
#process.crawl(JobsSpider6)
#process.crawl(JobsSpider7)
#process.crawl(JobsSpider8)
#process.crawl(JobsSpider9)
#process.crawl(JobsSpider10)
#process.crawl(JobsSpider11)
#process.crawl(JobsSpider12)

#################################################
This does not work below 

configure_logging()
runner = CrawlerRunner()
#
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    yield runner.crawl(JobsSpider1)
    yield runner.crawl(JobsSpider2)
   #yield runner.crawl(JobsSpider3)
   #yield runner.crawl(JobsSpider4)
   #yield runner.crawl(JobsSpider5)
   #yield runner.crawl(JobsSpider6)
   #yield runner.crawl(JobsSpider7)
   #yield runner.crawl(JobsSpider8)
   #yield runner.crawl(JobsSpider9)
   #yield runner.crawl(JobsSpider10)
   #yield runner.crawl(JobsSpider11)
   #yield runner.crawl(JobsSpider12)
#
   reactor.stop()
#
crawl()
reactor.run() the script will block here until the last crawl call is finished
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry about that, I just updated the posting @Gallaecio

Comment: Is all of that code needed to reproduce the issue? oO